# JIRA Rest API call returning " the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found " on posting attachment via ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, html5-canvas, jira-rest-api

I am posting attachment to JIRA rest api through an ajax call but it fails in "the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found ". I followed the instructions provided on jira doc but still facing this issue. Here is code snipped :

```
var imageDataUrl = canvas.toDataURL();
$.ajax({
 url: "https://example.atlassian.com/rest/api/2/issue/" + issueKeyid + "/attachments",
 type: 'POST',
 data: {
  file: imageDataUrl
 },
 processData: false,
 contentType: 'multipart/form-data',
 beforeSend: function(xhr) {
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(username + ":" + password));
  xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Atlassian-Token","no-check");
 },
 success: function(data) {
  alert("issue created");

 },
 error: function(data) {
  console.log(data);
 }
});
```

Here imageDataUrl is obtained from html canvas method asDataUrl(canvas).
I tried with curl and everything works fine.

What went wrong with code. Is there anything else I have to consider ?

Comment: What error message did you get on the [error] callback?

Comment: the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found

Comment: I am unable to figure the perfect way to transfer this imageDataURL to jira. What would be the best way to send this imageData as attachment to jira ?

Comment: Alright, We'll figure this out. I'll find another way to transfer the attachment on jira.

Comment: @eeya thanks ! that would be quite helpful. I really appreciate this

Comment: Is there a reason why you wanted to do this in ajax instead of curl as you have mentioned in your question? https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/cloud/?_ga=1.22532412.681630190.1490518356#api/2/issue/{issueIdOrKey}/attachments

Comment: as I am developing a jira web client so will need to make ajax call.

Comment: @eeya did you try this, sending attachment to jira via some api call ? 
 I am still stuck at this point. unable to figure it out.

Comment: Sry about the delay, but let me verify this. As I have checked your code snippet, you wanted to pass the 'base 64' image url which will be passed from this [ajax] to jira's [api] post attachment?

Comment: Yes. So that it get's uploaded to the existing issue on jira.

Answer (score 1):

After few hiccups I figured out the way to post attachment to jira. There was something the needed to be done before passing base64 image directly to jira. 
Here is my final version of code.

```
                            var blob = BG.dataURItoBlob(items.screenshotImg);
                            var fd = new FormData();
                            fd.append("file", blob);
                            fd.append('comment', "img");
                            fd.append('minorEdit', "true");

                            $.ajax({
                                url: "https://"+jiraUrl+"/rest/api/2/issue/"+issueKeyid+"/attachments",
                                type: 'POST', 
                                data: fd,
                                processData: false,
                                contentType: false,
                                headers: {
                                    "X-Atlassian-Token": "nocheck"
                                },
                                success: function(data) {
                                    status = "success";
                                    console("success");

                                },
                                error:function(data){
                                    status = "failed";
                                    console("Something went wrong !!");
                                }
                            });
```

Here I am converting the base64 image url to blob data first then sending it as a FormData object as a whole to server.

```
//base64 to blob data
function dataURItoBlob(dataURI) {
    // convert base64/URLEncoded data component to raw binary data held in a string
    var byteString;
    if (dataURI.split(',')[0].indexOf('base64') >= 0)
        byteString = atob(dataURI.split(',')[1]);
    else
        byteString = unescape(dataURI.split(',')[1]);

    // separate out the mime component
    var mimeString = dataURI.split(',')[0].split(':')[1].split(';')[0];

    // write the bytes of the string to a typed array
    var ia = new Uint8Array(byteString.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
        ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
    }

    return new Blob([ia], {type:mimeString});
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about the late reply.

You might need to change the way you assigned your [$.ajax] method. Instead of passing a base 64 url image, You can pass the whole attachment file you wanted to upload that you will also get from your server side (e.g PHP) in which you can post your attachment using [curl].

Assume you've place your [file input] inside a [form] DOM element

```
<form id="frm-upload" name="frm_upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" name="input_text" />
    <input type="file" name="input_upload_file" />
</form>

<a class="upload"> Upload </a>
```

Then in your [ajax] callback

```
$(sElement).click(function(event) {
     event.preventDefault();
     var oFormData = new FormData($('#frm-upload')[0]); // Assuming this is your form
     $.ajax({
         url: '/dashboard/upload',
         type: 'POST',
         data: oFormData,
         contentType: false,
         processData: false,
         beforeSend: function(xhr) {
             xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa('username' + ":" + 'password'));
             xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Atlassian-Token","no-check");
                },
         success : function(response) {
             console.log(response);
         }
    }, 'json');
});
```

Then you can get the uploaded file in PHP:

```
protected function upload()
{
    var_dump($_FILES); exit;
}
```

From which you can have the results:

```
array(1) {
["input_upload_file"]=>
    array(5) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(12) "service6.png"
    ["type"]=>
    string(9) "image/png"
    ["tmp_name"]=>
    string(14) "/tmp/php0bYNIY"
    ["error"]=>
    int(0)
    ["size"]=>
    int(1169)
  }
}
```

Which you can use [curl] to do this:

```
curl -D- -u admin:admin -X POST -H "X-Atlassian-Token: no-check" -F   "file=@service6.png" http://example.atlassian.com/rest/api/2/issue/TEST-123/attachments
```

As documented in Jira's Post Attachment API:

https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/cloud/?_ga=1.22532412.681630190.1490518356#api/2/issue/{issueIdOrKey}/attachments

Hope this helps for your case.

Comment: thanks for your effort eeya. I really appreciate this. As I am not using any server side here. It's been done totally as client side request. I resolved this issue in some other way. Please see my answer.